# Trouble setting camera follow target up

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game object instantiated using photon network as so:

```
GameObject myPlayerGO = (GameObject)PhotonNetwork.Instantiate("PlayerModel", mySpawnSpot.transform.position, mySpawnSpot.transform.rotation, 0);
```

This script sits in a SCRIPT game object in my scene. ie,
[image]

I want to have my camera called "Camera" with the smoothfollow script setup as follows:
[image]

I basically want to set the target of the smooth follow script to the game object instantiated by Photon Network.

I've tried various variations of the code:

```
GameObject.Find("Camera").GetComponent<SmoothFollow>().target = myPlayerGO;
GameObject.Find("Camera").GetComponent("SmoothFollow").target = myPlayerGO;
GameObject.Find("Camera").GetComponent(SmoothFollow).target = myPlayerGO;
```

But get various different errors not letting me do this. All the documentation and other forum posts i've found suggested that this code should work.

If someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong that would be great

Normally I would just have the camera part of the game object, but I'm using a script to make my gameobject turn towards my mouse, and it does funny thing with the camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

myPlayerGo is of type GameObject.
The smooth follow script's "target" is of type Transform as indicated by the None (Transform) in the inspector.
Try

```
GameObject.Find("Camera").GetComponent<SmoothFollow>().target = myPlayerGO.transform;
```

Comment: I'm getting an error saying SmoothFollow doesn't exist in current context in my IDE. (seems to work fine tho!)  Is there a way to fix that for my IDE purposes?

Comment: @Wilson This is obvious but do you have a using statement for the namespace of the SmoothFollow script?(if there's a namespace) Also make the SmoothFollow class public if it isn't (if there's nothing in front of the class declaration it's internal by default). If this doesn't work then I don't know, can't help you in comments.